# Will C++ function with mixed constant value and variable enable copy elision too?

Tags: c++

In the following code

```
std::string OtherFunc();

std::string MyFunc() {
    if (condition1) return "result 1";
    if (condition2) return "result 2";
    return OtherFunc();
}
```

Will `MyFunc()` enable copy elision (for the return string from `OtherFunc()`)? I know I can  write

```
std::string MyFunc() {
    std::string ret;

    if (condition1) {
        ret = "result 1";
        return ret;
    }

    if (condition2) {
        ret = "result 2";
        return ret;
    }

    ret = OtherFunc();
    return ret;
}
```

to 100% sure copy elision enable. But I think the 2nd code is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `std::string` copies/moves made in the first example you are showing. (since C++17)

In the second variant the move from `ret` to the return value of the function (or whatever object is initialized from it) *may* be elided (named return value optimization (NRVO)), but that is not guaranteed, even in C++17.

Furthermore in the second example, even if NRVO is applied, there will need to be a move assignment operator call for the line `ret = OtherFunc();` that isn't required in the first version.

So, the first version is definitively better in terms of the required copy/move operations. (A `std::string` move can still be cheap, so the difference may not be significant enough that other factors won't determine the overall performance.)